# @KafkaListener setting properties using SpEL expression

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka, spring-el

Is it possible to use SpEL to inject a list of properties into the @KafkaListner annotation?

Something like this:

```
@KafkaListener(topics = "topic-name",
            containerFactory = "myContainerFactory",
            groupId = "group-id",
            properties = "#{kafka.consumer.custom.properties}")
    public void onMessage(String msg) {
        log.info(msg);
    }
```

application.yml

```
kafka:
  consumer:
    custom:
      properties:
        key.deserializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.IntegerDeserializer
        value.deserializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/issues/1880#issuecomment-887677779

```yaml
some:
  prop: |
    max.poll.records: 10
    fetch.min.bytes: 123456
```

```java
@KafkaListener(id = "kgh1880", topics = "kgh1880",
            properties = "${some.prop}")
```